# Is $\mathbb{R}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think I've been confusing myself about the language of subspaces and so on.  This is a rather basic question, so please bare with me.  I'm wondering why we do not (or perhaps "we" do, and I just don't know about it) say that $\mathbb{ R } $ is a subspace of $\mathbb{ R }^2 $.  It's elementary to prove that the set
$$ S:= \left\{ c \cdot \mathbf{x} \mid c \in \mathbb{ R }, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{ R }^2  \right\}$$
is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{ R } ^2$.  What is confusing me is that there seems to be an isomorphism between the set $S$ and $\mathbb{ R } $:
\begin{align*}
\varphi: S &\rightarrow \mathbb{ R }   \\
 c \cdot \mathbf{x} &\mapsto c \\
\end{align*}
If this is indeed true, as I believe it is having checked that $\varphi$ gives an isomorphism, wouldn't we say that $\mathbb{ R } $ is a subspace of $\mathbb{ R } ^2$?
Any help sorting out this (language) problem will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The way you've written it, $S = \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Perhaps you should define $S_{\bf x}:=\{c\cdot {\bf x}: c\in \mathbb{R}\}$ for each ${\bf x}\in \mathbb{R}^2$. In this case you have many copies of $\mathbb{R}$ (whenever ${\bf x}\neq {\bf 0})$.

Comment: I like this question and I think that such a short, simple question should have a simple, short answer.  $\mathbb R^2$ is defined to be the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $x,y \in \mathbb R$.  By this definition, $\mathbb R$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^2$.  Therefore, $\mathbb R$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Didn't we have this discussion already in the form "Is $\Bbb R$ a subset of $\Bbb C$" a few times in very recent history?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think that's a different story, since there is only one possible embedding of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb C$ as a subfield. In contrast to the many embeddings of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R^2$ as a subspace.

Comment: @Christoph: No, there are many many many many many ways to embed $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb C$ as a subfield. Only one way is "natural" though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, I didn't know of other embeddings, I'm surprised! Thank you.

Comment: @Christoph: Extend $\Bbb R$ by adding any number (between $1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$) of transcendental elements, then take an algebraic closure of this field, then that algebraic closure is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$. So by usual argument $\Bbb R$ embeds into it, but this embedding is very different than the usual embedding since the degree of $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb R$ now is not $2$, but infinite. And there are many many other ways of doing similar tricks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is indeed an important question. No doubt that $\mathbb{R}$ is *isomorphic* to many subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or in other words, $\mathbb{R}$ can be *embedded* in many ways in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The thing is that there isn't any specific subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is the best one to represent $\mathbb{R}$.

If you want to treat $\mathbb{R}$ as a subspace, you need to specify the embedding $\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ you refer to.

I would say that as long as we don't *choose* the embedding, $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I'll add that, colloquially, it's often said that $\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, when what is really meant is, as you say, something like $\mathbb{R} \times \{ 0 \}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is much the same as in group theory, where we might say $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$; it arises from only really caring about algebraic structures up to isomorphism.

Comment: Note that saying that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is slightly different, since there is a *unique* embedding.

Comment: However, it is true that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: That's a bit nitpicky, but alright... $\mathbb{Z}_2 \le \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ would be an example where there is *not* a unique embedding. (And yes, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ isn't a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, but it's isomorphic to one, in much the same way that $\mathbb{R}$ isn't [but is isomorphic to] a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Comment: I'm not saying your answer's wrong, in fact I up-voted it, I'm just adding that what's technically correct is often not what is written by mathematicians when the technically correct translation ("is" -> "is isomorphic to") is understood from context.

Comment: I agree, it's true. I just pointed out that there are a few different kinds of all these cases.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, so rather I would specify the subspace $Y$ of $\Bbb R^2$ and then say that $Y\cong \Bbb R$?

Comment: @FunctionalAnalysis Yes, that would make more sense.