# Algebraic complements in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

Definition: $Z$ is called an algebraic complement of $Y$ in $X$ if $X=Y\oplus Z$.

---

Example: $Y=\Bbb R$ is a subspace of the Euclidean plane $\Bbb R^2$. "Clearly, $Y$ has infinitely many algebraic complements in $\Bbb R^2$."

I don't find this entirely clear, unless this is it:

$Y = \Bbb R = \{(y,0): y\in \Bbb R\}$, $Z_a=\{(a,z):z\in \Bbb R\}$, then we obtain $X=Y\oplus Z_a, \forall a\in \Bbb R$, is that what they are getting at?

Comment: Is $Z_a$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Try to think about lines of different slopes instead.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh doh, that was stupid of me, of course we need $(0,0)$ to occur, which pins $a=0$ in that configuration, or alternatively we can set any $(az,bz)$ instead, this gives us an actual linear subspace.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I would be thankful if you were still here to verify the above is correct

Comment: You say $\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$... Maybe you should read this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897775/is-mathbbr-a-subspace-of-mathbbr2/897788#897788.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Najib says, the set $Z_a$ is not a linear subspace whenever $a\neq0$.

However, yes, the space $Y$ in your question has infinitely many algebraic complements in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact, for *any* $v\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus Y$, we have $\mathbb{R}^2=Y\oplus\mathrm{span}(v)$.